# Installing a network simulator PiccSIM on Ubuntu

Tags: networking

I am currently working on my research on security issues associated with Wireless Sensor Network Control Systems. 
Also i have been trying to install PiccSIM on Ubuntu for a few days now but i keep getting the following errors:

> marolinks@ubuntu:~/Desktop/Ns2/PiccSIM_ns-2.34_bundle$
>   ./installPiccSIM_1.00_2.34.sh ./installPiccSIM_1.00_2.34.sh: 3:
>   ./installPiccSIM_1.00_2.34.sh: make: not found
>   ./installPiccSIM_1.00_2.34.sh: 5: ./installPiccSIM_1.00_2.34.sh: cp:
>   not found ./installPiccSIM_1.00_2.34.sh: 6:
>   ./installPiccSIM_1.00_2.34.sh: patch: not found ./configure: 4:
>   ./configure: sed: not found ./configure: line 182: sed: command not
>   found ./configure: line 446: expr: command not found ./configure: line
>   458: sed: command not found ./configure: line 472: sed: command not
>   found : error: cannot create .lineno; rerun with a POSIX shell
>   ./installPiccSIM_1.00_2.34.sh: 9: ./installPiccSIM_1.00_2.34.sh: make:
>   not found marolinks@ubuntu:~/Desktop/Ns2/PiccSIM_ns-2.34_bundle$

Please can i get any support from you on how to resolve this

Answer (score 1):

---

> make: not found

Solution : $ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install make sed coreutils

---

---